# Check Cell formatting in JavaScript for Excel

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins

Within an **Office Excel JavaScript Add in**, I would like to use conditional formatting to format a "Check Cell".

I have written the following code:

```js
function CLCC() {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var range = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
        range.format.horizontalAlignment = "Center";
        range.format.verticalAlignment = "Center";

        let conditionalFormatting: ExcelScript.ConditionalFormat;

        conditionalFormatting = range.addConditionalFormat(ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.cellValue);
        conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().setRule({ operator: ExcelScript.ConditionalCellValueOperator.equalTo, formula1: "=TRUE" });
        conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().getFormat().getFont().setColor("#808080");
        conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().getFormat().getFont().setBold(false);
        conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().getFormat().getFont().setItalic(true);
        conditionalFormatting.setStopIfTrue(false);
        conditionalFormatting.setPriority(0);

        conditionalFormatting = range.addConditionalFormat(ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.cellValue);
        conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().setRule({ operator: ExcelScript.ConditionalCellValueOperator.equalTo, formula1: "=FALSE" });
        conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().getFormat().getFill().setColor("#ffabab");
        conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().getFormat().getFont().setColor("#000000");
        conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().getFormat().getFont().setBold(true);
        conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().getFormat().getFont().setItalic(false);
        conditionalFormatting.setStopIfTrue(false);
        conditionalFormatting.setPriority(0);

        return ctx.sync()
    }).genericErrorHandler(error)
}
```

However, this code does not seem to work due to the following error:

```
Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files
```

How can I rewrite this code to properly execute in an JS function file for an office add-in? I am expecting the code to execute as part of a custom ribbon excel add-in

**Updated code base**

```
function CLCC() {
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var range = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
    range.format.horizontalAlignment = "Center";
    range.format.verticalAlignment = "Center";

    conditionalFormatting = range.addConditionalFormat(Excel.ConditionalFormatType.cellValue);
    conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().setRule({ operator: Excel.ConditionalCellValueOperator.equalTo, formula1: "=TRUE" });
    conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().getFormat().getFont().setColor("#808080");
    conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().getFormat().getFont().setBold(false);
    conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().getFormat().getFont().setItalic(true);
    conditionalFormatting.setStopIfTrue(false);
    conditionalFormatting.setPriority(0);

    conditionalFormatting = range.addConditionalFormat(Excel.ConditionalFormatType.cellValue);
    conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().setRule({ operator: Excel.ConditionalCellValueOperator.equalTo, formula1: "=FALSE" });
    conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().getFormat().getFill().setColor("#ffabab");
    conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().getFormat().getFont().setColor("#000000");
    conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().getFormat().getFont().setBold(true);
    conditionalFormatting.getCellValue().getFormat().getFont().setItalic(false);
    conditionalFormatting.setStopIfTrue(false);
    conditionalFormatting.setPriority(0);

    return ctx.sync()
}).genericErrorHandler(error)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the type declaration from the line `let conditionalFormatting: ExcelScript.ConditionalFormat;`.

Comment: Hey Rick - thanks for the reply! I have updated the code based on your suggestion (see "Updated Code Base" above). However, it is still not executing correctly. Any further suggestions? Thanks so much in advance - really highly appreciated!

Comment: Are still getting the same error about TypeScript? If so, see if your `genericErrorHandler` has a type annotation.

Comment: Actually not getting an error anymore - However, the function is still not executing:
-The conditional formatting is not applied to the selected cell
-In general, there seems to be no adjustment to the selected cell, although the code is running

Any idea what could be the reason for that? Thanks in advance and have a great wekend!

Comment: You now have a different problem, so you should create a new Stack question. Also, see if you can reproduce the problem using the Script Lab tool.